# gcloud app deploy suddenly fails

Tags: google-app-engine, gcloud

I'm running `gcloud app deploy` on a simple python project and deploys are suddenly failing. I've tried rolling back the gcloud components version and rolling back my codebase.

We've tried multiple computers and networks and no one can deploy.

The error and logs don't provide much clarity:

`Errors were encountered while copying files to App Engine.`

Here's my app.yaml:

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true
default_expiration: '1m'

handlers:
  - url: /assets/
    static_dir: assets/
    secure: always
    http_headers:
      X-Frame-Options: "DENY"
      Strict-Transport-Security: "max-age=2592000; includeSubdomains"
      X-Content-Type-Options: "nosniff"
      X-XSS-Protection: "1; mode=block"
  - url: /build/
    static_dir: build/
    secure: always
    http_headers:
      X-Frame-Options: "DENY"
      Strict-Transport-Security: "max-age=2592000; includeSubdomains"
      X-Content-Type-Options: "nosniff"
      X-XSS-Protection: "1; mode=block"
  - url: /.*
    script: main.app
    secure: always

libraries:
  - name: django
    version: latest
  - name: jinja2
    version: latest
  - name: webapp2
    version: latest

skip_files:
  - node_modules/
  - public/
  - src/
  - ^.git/.*
  - ^node_modules/(.*/)?
  - .*node_modules
  - ^js/(.*/)?
  - ^less/(.*/)?
  - bin/
  - ^(.*/)?.*\.py[co]$
```

Comment: Try to increase `gcloud app deploy`'s verbosity maybe you can get more info about the problem, see `--verbosity=VERBOSITY` at https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/ for details.

Comment: Just adding up to what @DanCornilescu said, could you please update the question with what the `gcloud app deploy` command returns with the added verbosity (with special relevance to the warning and error levels)?

Answer (score 1):

`gcloud` uses a cloud storage bucket to upload your files to Google (since Google can't read the files on your local computer). It's possible that you list access to the default bucket for this (which I believe is `staging.$APPNAME.appspot.com`).

You can try using the [--bucket](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/deploy) flag to stage code to a different bucket, or the `gcloud beta app repair` command to recreate the bucket if you find that it's missing.